# Audio not working for rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, pulseaudio, espeak

I am using `espeak-ruby` gem on my rails app and it is working fine on my local machine. When I deployed to heroku, the app did not work because there was no espeak installed on heroku. Then I used the [build-buildpack-apt](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to install espeak on heroku. Installing espeak the app works but there is no sound. I got an error `libpulsecommon-11.1.so not found`. Then I tried adding `libpulse0` package but still got the same error.

I also tried installing `libpulse-dev` and `pulseaudio. But none of those package get me libpulsecommon-11.1.so  library installed.

Comment: How are you expecting your application to work? If you manage to run espeak on Heroku it will try to play audio _on the server_, not on the user's browser. The reason it seems to work locally is that your server is local.

Comment: yeah I was thinking the whole thing wrong. I wanted to add text-to-speech feature and on a rails app and just got into rails gem rabbit hole. But ultimately I got what I wanted from 2 javascript lines.                                                        
`var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(word);
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg); `